# Mac equivalent of Inno?

Tags: installer

Basically I want to make a *Windows* installer, e.g. one that Windows users can use, 
I don't want to install Windows. I am making a game in Unity and want a user-friendly way to distribute it to Windows users, because I am on Mac.